# Why is the setup syscall not callable by any user?

Tags: kernel, system-calls

http://linux.die.net/man/2/setup

I didn't find any reason on the man page.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include Linus' answer to my email about the question of "why is setup() a syscall if user-space can never call it?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, that syscall no longer exists:

> Since Linux `2.1.121`, no such function exists anymore.

From what I can see in `2.1.120`, it was used in the init of the kernel (and in fact has syscall number `0`). It was only called twice: the first call freed the initial memory (from initram) and the second call sets up devices, filesystems and mounted the root. So clearly it would be bad if a program could run the syscall (it would cause segmentation violations or other bad things).

Why it's a syscall in the first place is a good question. For this I downloaded `1.0.0`, and *even then* the syscall was not used by an init (which was my first guess for why it would be a syscall). Even in `0.01` this was only used inside the kernel. Since there's no usage with `int 0x80`, I'm perplexed as to why Linus did this.

I've just sent an email to Linus & LKML and asked on IRC (although it's unlikely that anyone other than Linus will know, and he's fairly busy to be answering emails about the mitochondrial DNA of Linux).

EDIT: Okay, so looking into this further, it turns out that the kernel is actually calling it from a process context (the `setup` call actually acts as a syscall, `int 0x80` and all). The initialisation of the kernel was not done from within a process context, and ([according to Linus](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/9/21/647)):

> So the code actually goes into user space, but the very *initial* user
>   space is actually shared with the kernel (until the first fork()). We
>   do the initial user mode transition by just switching to user
>   segments [...] So in init/main.c, the magic is that

```
move_to_user_mode();
if (!fork()) {          /* we count on this going ok */
        init();
}
for(;;) pause();        /* [this is the idle task] */
```

> where that "move_to_user_mode()" will reload all the segments (some by
>   hand, but CS/SS by doing an "iret").  So that first fork() will
>   actually be done in user space, and before that happens the kernel
>   cannot sleep (because there is no idle task). [...] So "setup()" is a
>   system call because it needs to sleep (to do the IO), and the kernel
>   couldn't sleep before it got to that user-mode and first fork thing.
>
> Could it have been done differently? Sure. Obviously we don't do it
>   that way any more, and we create the idle tasks separately and not
>   with "fork()" any more. But it kind of made sense at the time.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer could not have been better.